# Best Electronics To Salvage Electromechanical Parts From

Tags: motor, components, solenoid

I know there have been 2 previous questions ([From what used/junk equipment can I salvage solenoids from?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57625/from-what-used-junk-equipment-can-i-salvage-solenoids-from) and [Taking apart old electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27210/taking-apart-old-electronics)) on this, but this one is a bit different.

Also, questions about salvaging parts [are on topic](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/salvage-questions-on-topic).

I always have lots of old electronics to take apart and salvage expensive or hard-to find parts (motors, solenoids, vacuum fluorescent displays, etc.) from. However, I have not been impressed with the amount of these parts I find in certain devices.

For example, I recently took apart a [laser printer](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/HP+LaserJet+1320+Teardown/45671).
Here are the usable parts that I got from it:

- 3 solenoids
- 1 2-inch fan
- 1 large brushless motor ([questionable](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/198674/how-to-use-a-salvaged-brushless-motor))
- 7 beam interruption sensors

This seems to be much less than other people get from taking apart laser printers. [This one](http://www.instructables.com/id/Harvesting-parts-from-a-Laser-Printer/step7/The-Spoils/) contained 10 motors, 10 beam interruption sensors, 9 microswitches, 2 electric clutches, and more parts.

What are the best devices to take apart to find these parts (list below)? Where is the best place to obtain these devices?

- DC motors
- Solenoids
- Stepper motors
- Brushless motors
- Vacuum fluorescent displays

Comment: Ugly thing with salvaging is that when you subsequently use the parts in a design, it will not be scalable. Many parts will be custom-made for the large laser printer manufacturer, and will not be freely and cheaply available in your location.

Comment: Few more posts about low merits of salvaging components out of random junk these days: [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/27214/7036) and [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/87190/7036).  (Applies well to US.)

Comment: Old VCRs are good for the parts you want to strip .

Comment: How is this different?

Comment: Junk the junk and buy new parts.

Comment: Are you playing a RPG? looks like something you might need for a Rock-it-launcher from Fallout. More serious: Printers always do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Back when I was in junior high some 55 years ago, I got hold of a pinball machine that had been seized in a raid and took it apart. Back then they were 100% electromechanical. Used the many relays, counters, solenoids, and micro switches to build all sorts of interesting stuff. One of today's arcade games, if you could get a hold of a non-functioning one, would probably also yield tons of interesting stuff. Or maybe you could still find one of the older ones too.-